# Tamanho de arquivos no windows e linux

Tags: linux, windows, servidor

Estou transferindo arquivos atraves do (FILEZILLA FTP Client) de minha maquina local que roda XAMPP/Windows8, porem ao colocar o arquivo no servidor LINUX os arquivos sofrem uma variação de tamanho.

Ex:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\app\arquivo.php :: Filesize 3.110 kb no windows
#apos fazer o upload par o servidor linux fica assim:
/home/app/public_html/arquivo.php :: Filesize 3.018 kb no linux
```

O arquivo continua igual, roda o script normal, sem erros

A pergunta é:

Essa mudança no tamanho do arquivo ao ser tranferido é normal? E porque acontece isso?

Comment: Talvez na hora das transferência os caracteres `\r` sejam removidos. Também note que no Windows tem "tamanho" e "tamanho em disco". Retirei a tag php, pois o problema não envolve ele. Só não irei tentar formular uma resposta amigo, por que a sua questão é off-topic.

Comment: Fiz o teste passei um arquivo via ASCII e o tamanho ficou igual e não houve perda do `\r`, a unica coisa que está diferente é o tamanho em disco, no Windows: tamanho: 15,9 KB (16.359 bytes)/tamanho em disco: 16,0 KB (16.384 bytes) --- Servidor: 16.359 bytes portanto acredito que você só esteja olhando para o local errado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não é o tamanho em disco, é o tamanho mesmo, clicando em propriedades do arquivo pelo windows ele mostra o mesmo tamanho em bytes que o filezilla.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz teste em ASCII e Binary e deu no certo.Tem que transferir em Binary para ficar igual.

Comment: Seu arquivo está usando `\r\n` ou `\n` para as quebras de linha? Se estiver usando `\r\n`, tente baixar o arquivo do servidor que está menor e veja se ele recupera o tamanho original. Se o tamanho voltou ao original, então acredito que pode ser o seu aplicativo de FTP que está com "algum" problema. Estou usando FileZilla 3.10.3

Comment: Esta não é uma pergunta relacionada diretamente a programação e está por ser removida. Considere utilizar um dos outros sites da [rede](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que você está fazendo uma transferência no modo texto e o Filezilla está mudando os caracteres que indicam o fim de linha do padrão Windows ("\r\n") para o Linux ("\n").

Tente mudar o modo de transferência para binário. Assim o arquivo manterá o formato e tamanho originais.

[Same file, different file size](https://superuser.com/questions/377743/same-file-different-file-size?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[ASCII vs Binary vs Auto?](https://serverfault.com/questions/110699/ascii-vs-binary-vs-auto?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[DOS vs. Unix Line Endings](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)

Comment: Transmitir arquivos ASCII como Binário? Vai dar problema.

Comment: O modo binário de transferência faz a cópia byte a byte, apenas isso.

Comment: Transmiti em ASCII e o tamanho e as quebras de linha não mudaram.

Comment: @LSouza sua resposta ajudou, tenho que transferir em binary para ficar igual. Pergunta: Como podem haver erros ao transferir de binary e ASCII ou vice e versa. Devo sempre deixar em AUTO ou devo selecionar uma das duas e usar como padrao?

Comment: Acho pouco provável que seja o `\r` o problema, pode ser alguma informação "Binaria" dentro do arquivo PHP. A não ser que seja algum BUG no FileZilla, as quebras de linha não mudam.

Comment: O que é mais correto, se modo texto, binário ou automático? Acho que depende do seu objetivo. Se for necessário editar o arquivo texto tanto no Windows quanto no Linux, o modo texto ou automático atenderá bem, pois fará a conversão necessária. Se a cópia for só pra fazer um backup para posterior download, com edições do arquivo texto sempre no Windows, o modo binário atende bem.